# No sound on iOS 9.0.2 devices

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, mp3

I am currently running the lastest version of Xcode for my Mac Xcode 7 and the following code I used to play sound. Sound plays during the iPhone simulator on the Mac but no sound on iOS 9.0.2 devices.

```
SystemSoundID sound;
AudioServicesDisposeSystemSoundID(sound);

NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"Whip" withExtension:@"mp3"];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &sound);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(sound);
```

This code works when I play it in the iPhone simulator on my Mac but when I try and test it on my iPhone 5C (iOS 9.0.2) no sound is played. How do I fix this issues because I have been struggling for a long time trying to figure out?

Comment: Filenames are case sensitive on a real device. Is the mp3 file really named `Whip.mp3` or is it really `whip.mp3` or some other name?

Comment: Yes the file name is "Whip.mp3". This is honestly very confusing for a beginner like me, has anyone one else experienced problems since the latest IOS update?